# Passing block to a method when the block needs a variable

Tags: ruby

This works, but it doesn't quite look right to me.  Was wondering what I'm missing or if I could simplify this somehow?

Abstract away the `$redis` stuff.

```
def redis_with_connection(&block)
    $redis.with_connection { |conn| yield(conn) }
    # perhaps do other stuff like begin/rescue, etc.
end
```

So then I can call this in my app

```
redis_with_connection do |conn|  # is this conn variable necessary here?
  conn.set # do stuff with the connection
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to yield the variable if you're just passing the block onto the `.with_connection` method. Instead, you can just pass the block as an argument:

```
def redis_with_connection(&block)
  $redis.with_connection(&block)
  # etc ...
end
```